# Structure data by rows from indented rows Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, powerquery, m

I have the following hierarchical data indented as the following image:
[image: hierarchical_data]

- Accounting Entry
- Date
- Description
- Accounting account

I would like to get each indentation level as a column in a new dataset, as in the following image:
[image: new_dataset]

I have tried to transpose matrix, power query m, without getting the desired result, there are many records and I need something as automatic as possible.

Maybe with python pandas I can do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How about changing the Excel report layout to "tabular form" with "repeated item labels" (2 clicks)? Alternatively, it's straight forward using the Fill-Down feature in PowerQuery.

Comment: The dataset is not a table... when i trying this solutions i get a pivot table with the four levels in the same field...

Comment: You have to provide sample data as markdown table, not jpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in one column then for PowerQuery, all you need to know is how to count leading spaces

```
 = Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1]))
```

From there, make a few if/thens, fill down, then filter

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Entry", each if Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1])) = 0 then [Column1] else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date", each if Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1])) = 1 then [Column1] else null),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Description", each if Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1])) = 2 then [Column1] else null),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Account", each if Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1])) = 3 then [Column1] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom3",{"Entry", "Date", "Description", "Account"}),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom", each Text.Length([Column1])-Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Column1]))),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom4", each ([Custom] = 3)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1", "Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]